# Can I Expose The Hashed Salt + Password?

Tags: security, hash, passwords, public, salt

I am using a SHA-512 hash 1000 times on a salt + password. Is it safe to return that when querying information about a user or should I secure it and make it available only over HTTPS?

For example, if I make the following request:

```
GET: http://domain.com/users?id=437
```

and it returns:

```
{"firstName":"Eliot","lastName":"My last name","email":"email@emailplace.com","password":[91,49,-34,77,79,-48,67,-62,-12,84,84,-18,-81,23,-92,-31,74,-28,-80,102,60,35,-102,115,18,-76,20,-90,-8,91,13,23],"authToken":"33c977b1-5ab6-4a8a-8da9-68c8028eff92","id":179}
```

does it matter that it is made public?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why has someone down voted Eliot's question? He has done the right thing by asking about something he is not familiar.

Comment: Good question, but seems a bit OT. [security.se] seems like a better choice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why would you **ever** return a user's password in response to any public-facing query? It doesn't matter what form the password is returned in -- this is fundamentally insecure!

Passwords can be cracked. Given a hash and knowledge of how the hash was constructed, you can bruteforce the relevant parameters. Even though it takes 1000 times longer, and the salt might have to be bruteforced (if not included in the query response), the possibility still exists (and someone patient enough, with the right resources, might just do it if the value was high enough). Don't take the risk -- just don't disclose the password in any form.

Comment: I am using Play framework and it automatically can renderJSON a model, which includes the password. I would only ever return a user's password because it is convenient. I am only asking this question out of curiosity of how possible it would be to do anything malicious given the super hashed password.

Comment: Yes, the password could be cracked, and users who reuse passwords may be severely compromised (beyond the scope of your site). Convenience should not trump security in such an important case. Leave the password out of the model if need be.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't expose any more information than necessary. Making it only available over HTTPS does nothing - I could just hit the URL via HTTPS and their password hash is still exposed.

Forget the password, you're also exposing the users' email address. Lock down whatever this API is.